# query a list of dynamic objects

Tags: linq, .net-4.0, lambda, microsoft-dynamics, massive

I am using [massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) to get the config table in the database. I would like to cache the config since the app gets values from it all the time.

once cached is there an easy way to find the object where name = 'something'

here is where the whole table is cached.

```
    protected override dynamic Get()
    { 
        var ret = HttpRuntime.Cache["Config"]; 
        if (ret == null)
        { 
            ret = _table.All(); 
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("Config", ret, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,CacheItemPriority.Low, null );
        }
        return ret; 
    }
```

here is where I would like to pull one record from that method

```
    protected override dynamic Get(string name)
    {
        return this.Get().Where(x => x.Name == name ).SingleOrDefault(); 
    }
```

I know linq or lambda statements are not allowed in dynamic objects. but what is the *next best* way to pull that one object out of that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not write the lamda expression directly as the Where argument, but you could assign it to a Func variable.
Also I believe extension methods would not work on dynamic objects, so you have to call the extension method directly.

I think you could use the below code,

```
        Func<dynamic, bool> check = x => x.Name == name;
        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<dynamic>(this.Get(), check);
```

Comment: how do i get the a Single element? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978619/query-a-list-of-dynamic-objects-for-a-firstordefault

Comment: As the response in the other question, you may use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault