# query a list of dynamic objects for a FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, .net-4.0, lambda

The following code will return an Enumerable of dynamic objects.

```
protected override dynamic Get(int id)
{ 
    Func<dynamic, bool> check = x => x.ID == id;
    return  Enumerable.Where<dynamic>(this.Get(), check);
}
```

How do I select the **FirstOrDefault** so it is a single object not an Enumerable?

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828105/query-a-list-of-dynamic-objects) but just want SingleOrDefault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is probably

```
protected override dynamic Get(int id)
{ 
    return Get().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==id);
}
```

Since some people have had trouble making this work, to test just do a new .NET 4.0 Console project (if you convert from a 3.5 you need to add System.Core and Microsoft.CSharp references) and paste this into Program.cs. Compiles and runs without a problem on 3 machines I've tested on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        protected dynamic Get2(int id)
        {
            Func<dynamic, bool> check = x => x.ID == id;
            return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<dynamic>(this.Get(), check);
        }

        protected dynamic Get(int id)
        {
            return Get().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }

        internal IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
        {
            dynamic a = new ExpandoObject(); a.ID = 1;
            dynamic b = new ExpandoObject(); b.ID = 2;
            dynamic c = new ExpandoObject(); c.ID = 3;
            return new[] { a, b, c };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(program.Get(2).ID);
            Console.WriteLine(program.Get2(2).ID);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I get a compile time error "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: @eui165 I'm guessing you're not running .NET 4.0 then? As I asked about above at the accepted answer, the Func may be a workaround for an older DLR.

Comment: I could be totally off base here, and I like the way your answer is written better. but I am looking at the properties of the project and the target framework is .net Framework 4. yet I still get a compile time error.

Comment: @eiu165 Pasted a test program into the answer, compiles and works on my 3 machines without a problem. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Works awesome and looks great, easy to use. I needed to include  using System.Linq;

Answer (score 5):

You could use your code with `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`. Like this:

```
protected override dynamic Get(int id)
{ 
    Func<dynamic, bool> check = x => x.ID == id;
    return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<dynamic>(this.Get(), check);
}
```

Comment: Why the Func step? Workaround for an older DLR?

Comment: because we are querying a list of dynamics therefore there is no such x.ID

Comment: @eiu165 If you look at my answer below, it compiles and runs fine on .NET 4.0 (VS2010) and does not use Func.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, have you considered the fact that the output of Get() method is dynamic, so DLR could not match the type with extension methods. To the best of my knowledge, extension methods are resolved at compile time and they are reliant on using statements and object types.

Answer (score 0):

Just so?

```
protected override dynamic Get(int id)
{ 
    Func<dynamic, bool> check = x => x.ID == id;
    return Enumerable.Where<dynamic>(this.Get(), check).FirstOrDefault();
}
```